# Is there an alternative for the SendKeys class that will work with Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I cannot find any definitive information anywhere but the System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys class appears to have been blocked / disabled / depreciated in Windows 10.

I wrote a demo program that monitors the users keystrokes and if a user enters a known code it will pop up a form and then go off to a document database and return various strings (company names / addresses / contact lists etc) and replace the typed code with the retrieved string. SendWait is used to send the retrieved strings to whatever program typed the code.

I built the program on the companies Windows 7 desktops but when I ran it on my personal Windows 10 system it didn't work. A lot of reading later and I feel like a complete idiot but I cant let them take this project any further knowing that they wont be on Win7 forever.

So my question is has this sort of functionality definitely been disabled in Windows 10 or is there another way or method I would be able to use to achieve this behavior of inserting text into running programs.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `SendKeys`? Seems more likely to me that Windows 10 will block the keyboard sniffing part of your program. Probably suspected as an attempt to still passwords.

Comment: Rather then (effectively) working with raw windows messages, have you considered working via the [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) system?

Comment: You can also try to hook the windows API directly using [this interop](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event).

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this everyone. I am still working on it and it is still not clear. Will post when I have a solution. Zohar - yep it is sendkeys - the SendKeys function stopped being supported a long time ago and it appears Win10 is when Microsoft finally broke it. Damian - I looked into UI automation but is so big, with dependencies and geared towards testing that I don't think it is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Forum-Thread:

https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/49635-sendkeys-not-working-windows-10-a.html

> SendKeys is Blocked in W10. In W8.1 it still works.
>   There are other anoying things, like not allowing App to Read or Wright to Drive C. The "file" is there but W10 "hides" it or simply not allowing to access it.
>   There are Netwok problems also, not allowing App to work on LAN environement.
>   Well, my opinion is that W10 behaves like Malware to user PC. Useless.

They had no solution.

Comment: Thanks Kajkrow. They are right but I am pretty sure there is alternatives. I have been put onto another project but will get this working and post the code solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if Sendkeys works with some apps and not others. I can automate an older app by sending it keystrokes but newer apps like Chrome don't respond. The inconsistent behavior has seriously messed up scripts that worked fine under Win 7.

I have not found any official documentation that says that Sendkeys has been deprecated  so  the inconsistency looks to be a Windows 10 bug.

Comment: SendKeys is definitely unsupported and has been for a very long time. It looks like Windows 10 has done something that has broken it where has previous versions of windows did not support it but did not break it either.